# Commenting out portions of code in Scala

Tags: scala, comments

I am looking for a C(++) `#if 0` -like way of being able to comment out whole pieces of Scala source code, for keeping around experimental or expired code for a while.

I tried out a couple of alternatives and would like to hear what you use, and if you have come up with something better?

```
// Simply block-marking N lines by '//' is one way... 
//  <tags> """ anything
```

My editor makes this easy, but it's not really The Thing. It gets easily mixed with actual one-line comments.

Then I figured there's native XML support, so:

```
<!-- 
  ... did not work
-->
```

Wrapping in XML works, unless you have `<tags>` within the block:

```
class none { val a= <ignore>
  ...
  cannot have //<tags> <here> (not even in end-of-line comments!)
</ignore> }
```

The same for multi-line strings seems kind of best, but there's an awful lot of boilerplate (not fashionable in Scala) to please the compiler (less if you're doing this within a class or an object):

```
object none { val ignore= """ This seems like
  ...
  <truly> <anything goes> but three "'s of course
""" }
```

The 'right' way to do this might be:

```
/***
  /*
  ... works but not properly syntax highlighed in SubEthaEdit (or StackOverflow)
  */
***/
```

..but that matches the `/*` and `*/` only, not i.e. `/***` to `***/`. This means the comments within the block need to be balanced. And - the current Scala syntax highlighting mode for SubEthaEdit fails miserably on this.

As a comparison, [Lua](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.1) has `--[==[` matching `]==]` and so forth. I think I'm spoilt?

So - is there some useful trick I'm overseeing?

Comment: I don't get why do you need to support `/*** /* ... */ ***/` nested-style blocks

Comment: It's probably better to just delete the code and if you want to get it back at some point use your version control system (or local history in your IDE).  It's just as quick once you're familiar with it, and cleaner.  Commenting out is a good way to accumulate cruft over time, and even with the best of intentions it rarely all gets cleaned up.

Comment: Can you clarify your use-case a bit more? You say "for keeping around experimental or expired code for a while." but it's not clear why just using /* */ is not good enough for that.  

As others pointed out, you want to avoid keeping large chunks of code not being compiled as you will have code-rot issues. So you may want to consider separating into files/modules/libraries for code that you aren't currently using, but may need in the future.

Comment: @om-nom-nom: All I really would like, I guess, is for syntax highlighting to work right with nested /*..*/ blocks. Then I can use multiple asterisks simply as a convention. To others: use case is really not large chunks, since Scala is pretty compact anyways. It's a way of working, i.e. I often make /*** REMOVE? ... ***/ blocks for methods or classes I might want to see for a few more days. Yes, version control is the next stage down. When I started this ticket, I thought nested /*..*/ did not work in the compiler, since syntax highlighting for them fails. Thanks for your opinions.

Answer (score 5):

Why not just make use of your source code control mechanism ? Keep the code separate, check it in as separate files and forget it. I wouldn't want my day-to-day code base cluttered up with this sort of stuff.

Note however that if you're not regularly using this code (e.g. in automated tests etc.) it'll suffer from [code rot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_rot). As soon as you comment out or otherwise shelve this stuff, dependencies will move on and you'll find that before long it just won't link against the existing code base.

Comment: Yes, in the long run this is exactly the approach I take. There is an 'Unused' folder for whole source files (that may rot). It's about granularity, I guess. First stage: comment out. Second stage: unused folder. Third stage: remove from the version control. Best working solution? Fix syntax highlighting in Scala editor I use. Ultimate solution: will check out upcoming Scala macros.

Answer (score 4):

I modified the Scala mode's `SyntaxDefinition.xml` to support `/***...***/` style comments.

This is not the same as the Scala parser's support for nested `/*...*/` comments, but I didn't find a way to express that for my editor.

In case someone wants to do the same, here goes:

```
<!-- AK 30-Nov-2012
-
- The Scala parser handles nested '/*...*/' style comments, but the SEE
- syntax highlighting seems not. 
-
- We introduce '/***...***/' style comments (starting with three asterisks
- since JavaDoc uses '/**..*/' style) and deeper levels, to be used for
- blocking out code blocks, even if they contain '/*..*/' comments within.
-
- Note: Original comment handling misses a 'type="comment"' field. Is that vital?
-
- Test: If this works right, the following will be highlighted as a single comment:
-     <<
-       /***
-       */
-       ***/    <- green, not black (note: Scala parses these differently; this is just to test the mode)
-     <<
-->
<state id="Multilevel Comment AK" color="#236E25" type="comment" font-style="italic">
  <begin><regex>/\*\*(?'commentCatch'\*+)</regex></begin>
  <end><regex>(?#see-insert-start-group:commentCatch)\*\*/</regex></end>
  <import mode="Base" state="EmailAndURLContainerState" keywords-only="yes"/>
</state>
```

You may also want to add `type="comment"` to the existing few comment highlight rules. I'm not sure if that is vital (other modes than Scala's do so).

Information on [SubEthaEdit modes](http://www.codingmonkeys.de/subethaedit/mode.html).

Comment: Upvote because this is the "right" answer. When one's editor doesn't syntax highlight a legal construct in one's chosen language correctly, one either chooses another editor or fixes the syntax highlighting. No doubt other users of this editor will thank you for heroically choosing the latter.

Answer (score 4):

There's one more option you've left out. Commenting of any sort has the downside of disabling syntax highlighting as well as not being included in IDE refactorings (Emacs+Ensime, IDEA, Eclipse, etc) or other code intelligence tools, I therefore prefer the following approach instead:

```
def ignore(block: => Any) = ()
def ignoreIf(cond: Boolean)(block: => Any): Unit = if (!cond) block

ignore {
  // experimental and/or disabled code
  syntaxHighlightingEnabled(true, 3, "foobar")
}

ignoreIf(SomeFeatureEnabled) {
  // experimental and conditionally enabled code
  syntaxHighlightingEnabled(true, 3, "foobar")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use 'degrees of delete'. (1) Comment out. (2) If it's code I don't need anymore but might find useful later/elsewhere, I have a **'.boneyard' folder** where I toss code fragments (just outside the production source tree) -- surprisingly handy. (3) Just delete it, and rely on source control if it turns out I need it after all.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the Lua programming language I use:

```
def */ = () // noop function, def or val


/*

println("Hello world!")
// more code

*/
```

to enable the whole code-block simply add one "/" to the "/*", i.e.

```
def */ = () // noop function


//*

println("Hello world!")
// more code

*/
```

Now it prints "Hello world!".

Comment: I don’t know how this is connected to Lua syntax (I know it until ~2012), or answers my original question. Anyways, this is long gone and I don’t seem to suffer from the same any more (maybe because moved to IntelliJ IDEA in the mean time).

Comment: From [Programming in Lua (first edition) ](http://www.lua.org/pil/1.3.html)